# Output parameters of 2d char arrays for a function

Tags: c, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

I was hoping if you can help me with some input and 2 dimensional arrays for this method of a program I am writing for an assignment. The programming language is C I got some input parameters:

> > FILE * ifp = input file pointer, opened up in main, opened a txt file with a format of 3 strings per line
> >
> > char ** firstTokens, middleTokens = 2 dimensional char arrays, I want them to hold the first two strings minus expected punctuation at the end of each string (such as commas and periods). Planned to be an output parameter.
> >
> > char * lastLetter = The first letter of whatever string is in the last column per line in the txt file. Planned to be an output parameter.
> >
> > int numberOfLines = number of lines I'm expecting to read from the text file

This is the call to the method in my main function:

```
readLine(ifp, firstTokens, middleTokens, lastLetter, numberOfLines);
```

I think my problem is with getting the `firstTokens` and `middleTokens` correctly, as I'm always getting compiler errors and segmentation faults in my edits. Some help/clarifications to the errors would be greatly appreciated.

```
void readLine(FILE * ifp, char ** firstTokens, char ** middleTokens, char* lastLetter, int numberOfLines)
{
    char* tempFirst;
    char* tempMiddle;
    char* tempLast;
    char delim[4];
    delim[0] = '.';
    delim[1] = '\0';
    delim[2] = '\n';
    delim[3] = ',';
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
    {
        fscanf(ifp, "%s %s %s", tempFirst, tempMiddle, tempLast);
        *firstTokens[i] = strtok(tempFirst, delim);
        *middleTokens[i] = strtok(tempMiddle, delim);
        lastLetter[i] = tempLast[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: char ** firstTokens is called a pointer to a pointer of(in your case) char. Unless you allocate memory for it, expect undefined behavior.

Comment: No memory has been allocated for targets of `fscanf()`.

Comment: Unfortunately `strtok` can not tokenize on the `'\0'` character. It wants a proper C string as its last argument, which means it _end_ on that character. So you only tokenize on the `'.'` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to allocate storage for `tempFirst`, `tempMiddle`, and `tempLast`.  `fscanf` writes to these pointers, assuming you've provided sufficient memory at them.

```
#define MAX_NAME_LEN (20) /* change this as required */
...
char tempFirst[MAX_NAME_LEN];
char tempMiddle[MAX_NAME_LEN];
char tempLast[MAX_NAME_LEN];
...
fscanf(ifp, "%s %s %s", tempFirst, tempMiddle, tempLast);
```

Comment: So I allocated appropriate memory for it, and now it compiles. Just another problem popped up: If I were to call a print statement such as: 

for(i = 0; i < numberOfNames; i++)
{
   printf("%s %s %c", firstName[i], lastName[i], middleInit[i]);
}

it prints out gibberish

Comment: Should you be assigning using `firstTokens[i] = strtok(...` ?  i.e. don't dereference `firstTokens[i]`

Comment: So I allocated appropriate memory for it, and now it compiles. Just another problem popped up: If I were to call a print statement such as:
 
`
for(i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
{
   printf("%s %s %c", firstTokens[i], middleTokens[i], lastLetter[i]);
}
`

it prints out gibberish
Edit: posted wrong code

And in the new code, firstTokens is not dereferenced. I think it's just how I created the arrays in the main method if that method logic is correct. I'll go ahead and review my code and fix up whatever is causing the hijink.

Thank you for your help, much appreciated